# Extrude multiple cylinders from one

Tags: modeling

I want to extrude three cylinders from one. I don't want to create another cylinder mesh, so this way I can avoid clipping

Here's exactly what I want:

https://gyazo.com/d9f9d82db16d75bb2386da1380c9022f

Thanks

Comment: Why is deleting the edge loops in between the separate cylinders not an option?

Comment: How many sides does your cylinder have?

Comment: 6, but with a subdivision surace modifier https://gyazo.com/8d13aa7de58bc14adbb86bc7471309c2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From 6 vertices for the base cylinder and 3 tentacles in the picture, you can assemble it in three parts :

- First assemble the extremity, extruding one vertex on two
- Extrude them (without moving)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to join them at center
- Then select more <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad+</kbd>
- And make the faces <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

- Now select the three faces as the extremity
- Extrude them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then "individual faces"
- Separate this faces a bit

[image]

- Now round them using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and move the mouse to the right and validate
- Then extrude again

[image]

Comment: How do I action Numpad+ if I don't have numpad?

Comment: use the 'select' menu, then 'select more or less' and chose 'more'. You can also just select the vertices with the mouse... oh and it is "ctrl"+"numPad+"... I did a mistake here